# Generating TypeScript interface from Objects

Tags: typescript

Edit: Broader question is whether TypeScript supports a preprocessor?

Is it possible in TypeScript (or related tools) to do:

```
[{ field: 'name', type: 'string' }, { field: 'age', type: 'number'}]
```

And generate an interface definition from this? I realize typescript checks things at compile time; and the reason I'm doing this is my list contains a few fields with metadata, and I wouldn't like to type this out again.

Are there any typescript directives?

Comment: That's an off-topic question as you're asking for a tool. With that being said, such a toll (or, something very similar) already exists: [json2ts](http://json2ts.com/)

Comment: You are right, I have seen this tool; but it seems like an offline procedure - I want to do this at build time automatically - I guess I could setup various build steps - but I was wondering if there was a more canonical way of doing this.

Comment: TypeScript will *infer* a type signature from this just fine, if you need to explicitly write out the type signature you could just copy the signature from the type hints (as shown in https://1drv.ms/i/s!Al6mzY0CpY7EnwnPZAnFyipQ2Oyi), write it out manually, or use the TypeScript compiler API to write an editor extension for generating it.

Comment: Well, how about this node package: [json-schema-to-typescript](https://github.com/bcherny/json-schema-to-typescript)?

Comment: Thanks @NitzanTomer, I wanted this question to be more of a discussion of whether typescript supports a pro-processor of some kind - however I see it doesn't. I'll close this question.

Answer (score -1):

> Are there any typescript directives?

No. But there are tools like `json2ts`. I even have it integrated in my IDE : https://alm-tools.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/json-to-dts.html

[image]